# grep output of command and display all lines that match a string

Tags: linux, bash, grep, ldap, freeipa

I'm trying to display all disabled accounts from the command:

```
ipa user-find --all
```

The basic output of the command shows something like this:

```
dn: uid=johnd,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=mydomain,dc=com
User login: johnd
First Name: John
Last Name: Doe
Full Name: John Doe
Home directory: /home/johnd
GECOS field: John Doe
Login shell: /bin/bash
Kerberos principal: johnd@DOMAIN.COM
Email address: johnd@domain.com
UID: 501
GID: 1022
Account disabled: True
Password: True
Member of groups: ipausers
Kerberos keys available: False
ipauniqueid: 75732ha-482x82l-13xa-d820-0120xbba142
objectclass: ipaobject, krbticketpolicyaux, etc.
```

If I run:

```
ipa user-find --all | grep "Account disabled: True"
```

I will get:

```
  Account disabled: True
  Account disabled: True
  Account disabled: True
  Account disabled: True
```

For all disabled accounts.  Is there a way I can have it display all the fields that match `"Account disabled: True"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And an awk solution that doesn't depend on order and/or presence of all attributes [and given my knowledge of ldif I'll safely assume that DN: is always on the first line]:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="\n\n";FS="\n"}/Account disabled: True/{print $1}'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ipa-user-find --all | grep "Account disabled: True" -B12 -A5
```

`-B` is how many lines before and `-A` is how many after. There's probably a more elegant solution, but this works for now.

If you want just the Full Name of each disabled account, just pipe your results to another grep command

Comment: Thank you.  This will do just fine.